# Set EditText cursor position to right of Hint Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor-position

I am writing an application where I need to set cursor position to right of Hint text.

I checked with some of available [answer](http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-default-field-value-and-showing-it-as-hint-in-edittext/) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296511/2624806) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22584080/2624806) but all these say with input text instead with only text hint.

Any suggestion if it is possible to have!

Comment: add addTextChangedListener to your edittext and if text.length is 0 set the hint text to your edittext